# What package does this symbol come from?

Tags: fonts

What package does this symbol come from? I've tried [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org) without success.

[image: Unknown font]

Comment: I think it may be a lowercase xi or uppercase E in some font package

Comment: `\usepackage{calligra}` and then `\textcalligra{E}`

Comment: Thanks @egreg, it was being used in a maths context which was sending me in the wrong direction.

Comment: definitely an uppercase E.  the E from `calligra` is much more heavily sloped than the one shown in the question.  the example letter is not from any of the alphabets listed in the comprehensive symbols list (`texdoc comprehensive`), table 213.  it may be a proprietary font.  where did the example come from, i.e., in what publication, from what publisher?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, [from this paper](http://or.journal.informs.org/content/55/3/569) in operations research journal. A non sloped version would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the font in question is definitively (a modified) "english script".  here is [an image](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/english-script/) showing a sample that includes the E.

the design of "english script" was originally from linotype.  the source of the font from which the OP posted the example was bitstream's "English157BT-Regular"; it was modified by unslanting it along with some minor editing.  (most "wedding scripts" are much too severely sloped to be suitable for math use.  "english script" is one of the more upright scripts, but even it is sub-optimal in its original form.)

i obtained this information from the person responsible for the font system at informs, the publisher of the *operations research journal* in which the symbol was found.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\begin{document}

\textcalligra{E}

\end{document}
```

See http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html

Although possible, the font is not suitable for math scripts. This is the test code for math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{mcalligra}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{mcalligra}{m}{n}{<-> s * callig15}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{calligra}{T1}{mcalligra}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathscr}{calligra}
\begin{document}

$x \in \mathscr{E}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: calligra does not give the same font

Comment: @GarethA.Lloyd: Indeed. But it is the most similar font available in a common TeX distribution. I downloaded the PDF and the font is denoted as `m4-101`, I've no idea about the real font name.